# Python + SOAP : The message with Action \'\' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, python-requests

Trying to access this soap webservice using python requests : http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFUploadService/MFUploadService.svc?WSDL

Here is my request :

```
import requests
url="http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/MFUploadService/MFUploadService.svc?WSDL"
#headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml'}
body = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <tem:getPassword>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:UserId>1003201</tem:UserId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:MemberId>10032</tem:MemberId>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:Password>xxxxxxxx</tem:Password>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:PassKey>xxxxxx123</tem:PassKey>
      </tem:getPassword>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""

response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)
print (response.content)
```

This the response :

> b'`Sendera:ActionNotSupported`The message with Action \'\' cannot be processed at
>   the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the
>   EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch
>   (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security
>   mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and
>   receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including
>   security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport,
>   None).'

If I understand correctly, I probably need to set the action in the request, but can't figure out how to do that. I'm entirely new to soap in python, please suggest how to fix this. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just add the SOAPAction onto the header, for example:

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8',
       'SOAPAction': 'http://google.com/ISearchService/Find'
       }
```